# When the monitor is connected, the dock should change its position

Tags: applescript

it is necessary that when the second monitor is connected, the dock becomes from the bottom (without the monitor on the left) and the programs should open from the monitor being launched.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Can you describe your monitor setup as well as what hardware and version of macOS you're running? Also, can you try to rephrase the above in to a question so we can better understand what it is you're having trouble with/trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

In `System preferences` -> `Displays` -> tab `Arrangement`, you can drag and drop the menu bar (white rectangle) to the desktop you want to be the master. System remembers that and everytime the same display model is connected it sets up automatically.

[image]

If you want to see the dock on the other screen, run the mouse pointer to the bottom of the screen and hold it there, the dock should move.

Comment: This may be dependent on which way you have 'displays have separate spaces' setup. [& it's not something I'm going to toggle to test, it causes too much mess to clean up afterwards]